# Multiple songs are playing,

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

Hello Every One I am trying to make music app in Android Studio. When I select a song in a recycler view, the song start playing in the new activity but when I go back to the songs list and select the new song both the songs start playing,I want that the previous song which was selected in the first place stop playing and new song start playing, How can I do it?

```
package com.recycler.hp.navigationbar;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class Revival_Activity extends Activity implements 
    OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener {

    private ImageButton buttonPlayPause;
    private SeekBar seekBarProgress;
    String editTextSongURL;

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds; // this value contains the song duration in milliseconds. Look at getDuration() method in MediaPlayer class

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_revival_);
        editTextSongURL=getIntent().getStringExtra("url");

        initView();

    }



    /**
     * This method initialise all the views in project
     */


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private void initView() {
        buttonPlayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause);
        buttonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);

        seekBarProgress = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBarTestPlay);
        seekBarProgress.setMax(99); // It means 100% .0-99
        seekBarProgress.setOnTouchListener(this);

        // editTextSongURL = getString(R.string.testsong_20_sec);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * Method which updates the SeekBar primary progress by current song playing position
     */
    private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
        seekBarProgress.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds) * 100)); // This math construction give a percentage of "was playing"/"song length"
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause) {
            /** ImageButton onClick event handler. Method which start/pause mediaplayer playing */
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(editTextSongURL); // setup song from http://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3 URL to mediaplayer data source
                mediaPlayer.prepare(); // you must call this method after setup the datasource in setDataSource method. After calling prepare() the instance of MediaPlayer starts load data from URL to internal buffer.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); // gets the song length in milliseconds from URL

            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }

            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.SeekBarTestPlay) {
            /** Seekbar onTouch event handler. Method which seeks MediaPlayer to seekBar primary progress position*/
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v;
                int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100) * sb.getProgress();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        /** MediaPlayer onCompletion event handler. Method which calls then song playing is complete*/
        buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        /** Method which updates the SeekBar secondary progress by current song loading from URL position*/
        seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple songs are playing when I click on listview in mediaplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438549/multiple-songs-are-playing-when-i-click-on-listview-in-mediaplayer)

Answer (score 0):

It’s possible that you’re creating multiple media player objects during your selections in your recyclerview. Try creating a singleton instance of media player that’s shared throughout your app and call mediaplayer.release() and then recreate before playing a new song.